# How Can I Get distance between Cell(Top, Bottom, Left, right)

Tags: swift

[image: Swift]

I Want to add distance between cells(Top and bottom) and distance between cells and table view's walls(left, right): I need to do it using by UIEdgeInset, not by adding headerView to cell:

Comment: Just add the cell's view in a `UIView` and then give it `UIEdgeInsets`.

Answer (score 0):

// Inside UITableViewCell subclass

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    contentView.frame = contentView.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2**

```
  override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        //set the values for top,left,bottom,right margins
        let margins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        contentView.frame = contentView.frame.inset(by: margins)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `cellforRowat` populate data according to section like `indexPath.section`. and add below method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.myTableView.frame.width, height: 10))
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    return headerView
}
```